# Check a command window is closed

Tags: excel, vba, batch-file

Below is the code we use to run to check the Ping and Trace for our site address. We have a userform which we need to enter some details and when we hit run this will start running. So when we start running it will create a batch file which (opens a command window) will first the ping and then the Trace. So the ping will finish within a 5 sec but the trace root will take some time and this is not a fixed time. Once both finish running the command window closes automatically. How do the macro knows the command window is closed so that we can enable a button in our userform to submit the report. We need a code to check whether the command window is closed and then it can go to the line "cmdFinishSlow.Enabled = True"

Please can anyone help me with this? Also this will not work in a 64bit Excel, is there any solution for that too?

```
    Dim address, NetStatAN, PingTextFile, BatchFile, TraceTextFile As String
    Dim row As Integer
    Dim inputline As String
    Dim lineitems() As String
    Dim Filepath As String
    
    Dim MyFSO As FileSystemObject
    Set MyFSO = New FileSystemObject
    
    Filepath = "C:\Users\" & Environ("Username") & "\Desktop\"
    BatchFile = "batchfile.bat"
    PingTextFile = "PingSite.txt"
    TraceTextFile = "TraceSite.txt"
    
    'Call Shell("explorer.exe" & " " & Filepath, vbNormalFocus)
    
    On Error Resume Next
    Kill (Filepath & BatchFile)
    Kill (Filepath & PingTextFile)
    Kill (Filepath & TraceTextFile)
    On Error GoTo 0

    row = 1
    address = Sheets("Slowness Issue").Range("C9").Value

    Do Until Trim(address) = ""
        Open Filepath & BatchFile For Output As #1
            Print #1, "ping " & address & " >>"; Filepath & PingTextFile
            Print #1, "tracert -d " & address & " >>"; Filepath & TraceTextFile
        Close #1

        Call Shell(Filepath & BatchFile)
        
        Application.Wait DateAdd("s", 5, Now) ' wait for 10 seconds      
        Open Filepath & PingTextFile For Input As #1

        Line Input #1, inputline       
        If Left(inputline, 10) = "Reply from" Then
            lineitems() = Split(inputline, " ")
            Cells(row, 2) = lineitems(2)
            Cells(row, 3) = Now
        End If

        row = row + 1
        address = Cells(row, 1)

    Loop
    
' Here I need to check the command window is closed or not

cmdFinishSlow.Enabled = True
cmdRunSlow.Enabled = False
```

Comment: You can use Findwindow API to check if the tracert cmd window is still open or not.

Comment: If you start the batch in your script perhaps you can use `wshShell.run` and the second optional parameter `[bWaitOnReturn]` to wait till the batch is ready https://www.vbsedit.com/html/6f28899c-d653-4555-8a59-49640b0e32ea.asp

Comment: `PING.EXE` and `TRACERT.EXE` are just command line executables, and do not require to be run from a Windows batch file. You could just run the `cmd.exe` process, with your uility as an argument, and you should be able to directly control/check the specific `cmd.exe` process, _(i.e. your target command window)_. To do that you could probably use `create` with `win32_process` and capture the returned `PID` from each `cmd.exe` process, then monitor that `PID`.